# Indent symbol for strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, format, symbols, indentation

I have to output a series of strings to the terminal. I can do that easy enough, however I want to indent the strings like so:

```
line 1
line 2
    line3
```

However, i'm not quite sure how to do so (Apart from a mass of spaces) or if its even possible, so I was wondering if, similar to the new line symbol, '\n' if there is a symbol capable of indentation?

Thanks for all the help!

Update:
Thanks for that!
I thought it might be something simple like that, but despite looking all over the internet, it wasn't something I could find, I guess I must have been using the wrong search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use '\t' for tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [string literal `\t`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (t for tab). Observe:

```
>>> s = """line 1
... line 2
... \tline3"""
>>> print s
line 1
line 2
    line3
```